# Why there is no task generateXXXSource in instant app module?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

For a project include installable, instant, and other modules, I can see there are gradle tasks of `:installable:generateGoogleReleaseSources`, `:<module_name>:generateReleaseSources` but I only see `:instant:dummyGoogleRelease` and there is no `:instant:generateGoogleReleseSources` (or any variant of it)

You can see it in action inside Android studio (this one is debug variant):

```
Executing tasks: [:instant:dummyDebug, :main:generateDebugSources, :detail:generateDebugSources, :base:generateDebugSources, :installed:generateDebugSources]
```

Is that supported? Cause I want to generate BuildConfig for instant app. The app module and the base module has it, instant module doesn't has it.

I tried put java sources, manifest, etc and same result.

(My android project has installable, instant, core (base feature), and many other library modules, as suggested by Google.)

Comment: The only thing `com.android.instantapp` is responsible for is to provide the build, based on the `implementation project()`'s in its dependencies, which modules should be built into instant app APKs. This module is not meant to hold any kind of code/resources.

Comment: But with App Bundles, Dynamic Features, and Android Studio 3.3 coming out, you should try to migrate to the newer instant app project setup. See `dist:instant="true"` @ https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features/blob/master/instant/url/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#configure

Comment: Oh, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425735/android-can-you-add-activities-to-the-instant-app-module